# Extracting certain values from an array and putting them in another array

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming so I'm sorry if this is to "noobish" a question.
I have an array containing values which describe the frequency of occurrences - e.g. {4,5,2,7,8,,15,16,12,4,2,7,6,22}. How do I extract the values that are **higher than 6** and present them in a new array?

Comment: Might help if we knew which language you're working with.

Comment: You do a run of the array an store the values that match your criteria elsewhere. To avoid creating an array of uncertain size, consider using an `ArrayList` and later "convert" it to array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer i: array) {
  if (i > 6) {
    newList.add(i);
  }
}
Integer[] newArray = newList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int j=0;
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
       if(array[i]>6)
         {

         newArray[j]=array[i];
              j++;
       }
```

this is the way you can do it or you can proceed.

Comment: How does he know the size of newArray?

Comment: as data is static newArray size can be taken as some appropriate number but in case if data is generated dynamically then list or set is the right way to do it.